# Codes for game (Rookie programmer here, FYI)

Tags: c

it is my first time here and I hope I will be a high activist here someday. However, I'm very new to C programming and I'm working on my school's project called traffic like RushHour game. I posted the sample board here. However, this program is pretty tough and I'm kinda pretty behind. So, I'm working on my functions for moving cars (letters will be used as cars). My program has to work with any kind of boards. I wrote the functions and I'm not sure if they are done correct since I kept getting errors on swap lines. I'm trying to get the cars and dots to swap correct. What did I do wrong here? Any feedback would be appreciated. I will accept insults or whatever.

```
- - - - - - - -
| G G . . . Y | 
| P . . B . Y |
| P R R B . Y >
| P . . B . . |
| O . . . T T |
| O . F F F . |
- - - - - - - -
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 64

void swap(char* board[], int *index1, int *index2) 
{ 
  char tempChar = *index1; 
  *index1 = *index2; 
  *index2 = tempChar;      
}

void moveCar(char* board[], char* vehicle, char* direction)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if(board[i] = vehicle)
    {
      if(*direction = 'r')
      {
        if(*board[i + 1] = '.')
        {
          swap((&board), (&i), (&i + 1));
        }
      }
      else if (*direction = 'l')
      {
        if(*board[i - 1] = '.')
        {
          swap(&board[], &(i), &(i - 1));
        }
      }
      else if (*direction = 'd')
      {
        if(*board[i + 8] = '.')
        {
          swap(&board[], &(i), &(i + 8));
        }
      }
      else if(*direction = 'u')
      {
        if(*board[i - 8] = '.')
        {
          swap(&board[], &(i), &(i - 8));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII This question doesn't look like a homework at all, plus I don't see how it is any normal to pick on amount of spaces for tabs like that... So it's rather more like: ***some people** are strange.*

Comment: Tests in your code are all wrong... you are assigning values in that way

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm very new to coding like I mentioned rookie programmer here. I really want to learn how to code like you guys here. So why do you think 5-space tabs is so strange? I really like my codes to be organized and clear.

Comment: @Cam9191 I just found it unusual - I've really only seen proponents of 2-space tabs, 4-space tabs and 8-space tabs, but never 5. There's nothing wrong with it, it just caught me off-guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking here, but let's assume the question is

> Why did I get the error `[Warning] passing arg 1 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer type`

The reason is because you are calling `swap` wrongly. You call it two ways:

```
swap((&board), (&i), (&i + 1));
```

and

```
swap(&board[], &(i), &(i - 1));
```

But `board` is declared as `char* board[]` in both cases, so all you need to do is:

```
swap(board, ... (whatever) ...);
```